# Blender won't render pose nor texture

Tags: rendering, texturing, rigging

Recently I've made my first character in blender. I sculpted it, made retopo using multires modifier, added texture and rig. In viewport everything seems just fine but when I render it, there isn't texture nor pose applied.
I checked if there aren't any keyframes and I think texture is applied in material well. Closing and reopening Blender doesn't work, when I try to render it on another computer it looks the same.

Edit: Solved,thank you so much for help. I'm sorry for wasting your time, it was such a stupid mistake.

In viewport: [image]
After rendering: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your *Outliner*, there is an object that we can see in render but not in preview, and another one that we can see in preview but not in render, you need to correct that:

[image]

Comment: Oh, you're right! Such a stupid mistake, thank you so much!